# How to open google ad on new tab?

Tags: php, html, seo

Whenever a visitor clicks a Google Ad on the site, the Ad opens in the same page, replacing my site, and I will lose the visitor.

Can we do something so that whenever a site visitor clicks on a Google Ad, it will open in a new tab? Is there any script that needs to be changed? I tried a `target="_blank"` but it is also not working.

Comment: target="_blank" should do the trick? Why wouldn't it work for you?

Comment: this script i used <div class="add"><a target="_blank"><script type="text/javascript">
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2155288333441066";
    google_ad_slot = "8846232633";
    google_ad_width = 336;
    google_ad_height = 280;
</script>
<!-- 10 how to fill color -->
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</a> </div>

Comment: Hi, did you check above msg

Answer (score 5):

***As adsense policy they do not allow Google ads to open in a new window. .***

**In DoubleClick for Publishers**

To change the target window setting for your network:

- In the 'Inventory' tab, click Network settings.
- Click edit next to    'Target window',
- then select '_blank' from the drop-down.
- Click Save.

To change the target window setting in an ad unit:

- Select an ad unit from the 'Inventory' tab.
- Click edit next to 'Target window',
- then select '_blank' from the drop-down.
- Click Save.

Comment: Thanks For Reply Ramesh. is DFP  work same as google addsence

Comment: DFP is a is a free ad management solution which will help you to grow yours sells, schedule, deliver, and measure all of your digital ad inventory. I haven't try it yet, but its free so take a look.. :p

Answer (score 1):

Please visit this link for [Opening the ads in a new window](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354740?hl=en)
 Google does not permit to open ads in new window.